# glGenVertexArrays error on openGL3+

Tags: python, opengl, opengl-3, pyopengl, vao

my professor just gave us a simple code that draws a triangle and it worked fine on the university lab. However at my personal computer I'm running into some weird error that I can't seem to find the solution on line. Up until now all openGL code worked just fine on my computer, so I would appreciate if anyone can tell me what is happening. The problem is with the function `glGenVertexArrays(1, vao)` when the code execute I get the following error:

```
ValueError: glGenVertexArrays requires 1 arguments (n), received 2: (1, c_uint(0L))
```

So from what I understood it only requires one argument but 2 are given, therefore I went ahead and removed the `1` getting `glGenVertexArrays(vao)`. But that also gives me an error:

```
TypeError: ('an integer is required', 'Failure in cConverter <OpenGL.converters.SizedOutput object at 0x7f582456c380>', (c_uint(0L),), 1, <OpenGL.platform.baseplatform.glGenVertexArrays object at 0x7f58244f3a28>)
```

From that error I got that I do need that integer, and after looking at the documentation for the function `glGenVertexArrays` I realized that the integer is only telling how many arrays there are so it should indeed be there. In a desperate attemp I removed the function completely and the code worked, a red triangle was shown to me. But what role does `glGenVertexArrays` plays in all this? Should I be removing it? After some research it found out the `VAO's` become required after openGL3+ and then I got confused because this is openGL3+ it uses shader's and it is not fixed function, what am I missing here?

Here is the code in python:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

vao = None;
vbo = None;
shaderProgram = None;

def readShaderFile(filename):
    with open('shader330/' + filename, 'r') as myfile:
        return myfile.read()

def init():
    global shaderProgram
    global vao
    global vbo

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    vertex_code = readShaderFile('hello.vp')
    fragment_code = readShaderFile('hello.fp')

    # compile shaders and program
    vertexShader = shaders.compileShader(vertex_code, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragmentShader = shaders.compileShader(fragment_code, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    shaderProgram = shaders.compileProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader)

    # Create and bind the Vertex Array Object
    vao = GLuint(0)
    glGenVertexArrays(1, vao)
    glBindVertexArray(vao)

    # Create and bind the Vertex Buffer Object
    vertices = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [-1, -1, 0], [1, -1, 0]], dtype='f')
    vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)  # first 0 is the location in shader
    glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, 'vertexPosition')  # name of attribute in shader
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  # 0=location do atributo, tem que ativar todos os atributos inicialmente sao desabilitados por padrao

    # Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO
    # as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    # Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs)
    glBindVertexArray(0);

def display():
    global shaderProgram
    global vao

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    # load everthing back
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram)
    glBindVertexArray(vao)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)

    # glDrawArrays( mode , first, count)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)

    #clean things up
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
    glBindVertexArray(0)
    glUseProgram(0)

    glutSwapBuffers()  # necessario para windows!

def reshape(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitContextVersion(3, 0)
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)

    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow(b'Hello world!')

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(display)

    init()

    glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: Just pass the `1` instead, removing `vao`.

Comment: @hashcode55 thank you! That worked, would you mind explaining why that is? I mean the original code has both 1 and vao and it works in the lab. And can you please post your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it worked in your lab, may be you got a buggy code. I'm pretty sure though that the [pyopengl](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGenVertexArrays.html) doc is wrong.

If you look at the [c++ doc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml) of openGL it says

> > void glGenVertexArrays(   GLsizei n,
> >         GLuint *arrays);
> >
> > n - Specifies the number of vertex array object names to generate.
> >
> > arrays - Specifies an array in which the generated vertex array object names are stored.

**But** if you look [here](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/opengl_diffs.html) it says theres no need to pass the said pointer and this is one of the differences between the python bindings of opengl and c++ lib.

And `glBindVertexArray(vao)` does the work of [binding the array](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexArray.xhtml) to the object.

So you just have to pass that `1` leaving `vao`.

*Moreover the error also clearly mentions it* -

`ValueError: glGenVertexArrays requires 1 arguments (n)`